# Is it possible to transfer all the plugins and settings?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA on my Mac for too long. My company asked me to use their laptop but I need all my plugins and settings. I've never used IntelliJ IDEA on another computer so maybe it's easy, I really don't want to install all the plugins one by one since there are too many.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Settings can be moved using `File` | `Manage IDE Settings` | **Export Settings** / **Import Settings** or the [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/settings-repository.html) plug-in.

As for the plugins, just [copy the plugins folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) from one system to another.

Comment: currently in   File -> Manage IDE Settings

Comment: How can you have settings get automatically imported when a new user opens the project?